# acomodar divs responsivos usando clip-path con imagen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo el problema que mi `div` se desacomoda al hacerla responsiva.

Tengo en primera instancia una fila hecha con `Bootstrap` donde se encuentra el menú, esa está bien, pero enseguida puse un a fila (`div` con `clip-path`) que tiene como fondo una imagen de un mapa mundi pero la línea de abajo del `div` debe ser en diagonal, para eso usé `clip-path`, y debajo viene otra fila que tiene la línea de arriba en diagonal para que aparezca junto a la fila (`div`) de arriba, en mi pantalla de escritorio se ve bien, pero al redimensionar a tamaño de celular la imagen del mapa mundi se corta, y las diagonales de las dos filas se desacomodan, quedando un espacio en blanco.....

Igual si hay otra alternativa la puedo usar.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.divheader {
  background-color: blue;
}

.divOtroHeader {
  background-color: red;
}

.divMenu {
  background-color: green;
}

.divServicio {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-12 divheader ">
        <span style="color: white">barra de titulo</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 ">
        <img class="img-fluid " width="100%" src="https://www.solofondos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/5EBBF494C.png" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 divOtroHeader">
        <span style="color: white">Otro div</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col divMenu">
        <div class="container ">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <img src="Imagenes/.png" class="img-fluid" style="width: 80px" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div style="float: right; height: 100%">
                <nav style="height: inherit" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  ">

                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                        </button>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav" style="height: inherit; ">
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="margin: 10px;" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">HOME</a>

                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" style="margin: 10px;" href="#">MENU1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" style="margin: 10px;" href="#">MENU2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" style="margin: 10px;" href="#">MENU3</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%------------------------------------------ CUADROS SERVICIO -------------------------------------------------------------------%>
      <div class="row " style="clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0 100%);  ">
        <div class="col " style="background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqdRNTyC_vki0Q_xo41JBmJIIFNhd3YKz2ZQgqWwaZLz23R3Df&s); background-size:  100%  100%; background-repeat: no-repeat ;">
          <div class="container ">
            <div class="row rowHome" id="services">
              <div class="col ">
                <div class="container" style="width: 80%; margin-top: 30px; text-align: center">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/analis.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/servicio.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/personalizada.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/celular.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/mano.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/engranes.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row mb-5 ">
                    <div class="col-md-12 d-inline-block  ">
                      <asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-primary btnSaberMas " ID="btnSaberMas" Text="Saber Más" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row mb-5 ">
                    <div class="col-md-12 d-inline-block  ">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row " style="clip-path: polygon(0px 20%, 100% 29px, 100% 100%, 0px 90%);background-image: url(Imagenes/fondo_puntos.png),url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-Eu6AKnvOfQ0msPIhWDJRRyKrOEsyKw27v7umxFrp23HKg3DG&s); background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat ; position: static; margin-top: -100px; width: 100%">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="container" style="margin-top: 90px; text-align: center">
            <div class="slide-left">
              <div class="inner">
                <div class="row ">

                  <div class="col col-sm-3 " style="margin-top: 40px">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWPfWn1I4P_E70snKLVtXTBb-NI7OnDXFEu5Rv1p8zIOosZPfm&s    " class="img-fluid" />
                  </div>


                </div>
                <div class="row ">

                  <div class="col col-sm-3 " style="margin-top: 40px">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWPfWn1I4P_E70snKLVtXTBb-NI7OnDXFEu5Rv1p8zIOosZPfm&s    " class="img-fluid" />
                  </div>


                </div>

              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div class="container  " style="margin-top: 90px;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4  " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs1" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div id="divContenido" class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " id="ima1" src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4   " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs4" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4   " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs5" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>




            </div>
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-sm-4  " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4   " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs2" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4   " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs3" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>

  <footer style="background-color :black ; padding-top: 1px; margin-top: 150px">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 90px; text-align: center">
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/facebook_CIO.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="col ">
          <label style="color: white">footer....</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="col ">
          <label style="color: white"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="col ">
          <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_facebook.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row rowHome" style="background-color: #000103 !important; opacity: 0.90">

        <div class="col-sm-8 Redes">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-linkedin" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 Redes">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</form>
```

Aquí una muestra del problema:

[image: Muestra del problema]

Comment: Por favor, comparte tu código para que algún compañero pueda ayudarte.

Comment: listo, ya se ve mi codigo, intente poner una imagen pero no se por que no la cargo

Comment: use clip-path, pero si hay otra alternativa estoy abierto a opciones

Answer (score 1):

El problema se genera porque le especificaste el `clip-path` también a la imágen del mapa con su respectiva deformación.

Yo no le haría nada y lo dejaría como

```
<div class="row " style="clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);  ">
```

o le subiría el valor a por lo menos 95%.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.divheader {
  background-color: blue;
}

.divOtroHeader {
  background-color: red;
}

.divMenu {
  background-color: green;
}

.divServicio {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-12 divheader ">
        <span style="color: white">barra de titulo</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 ">
        <img class="img-fluid " width="100%" src="https://www.solofondos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/5EBBF494C.png" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 divOtroHeader">
        <span style="color: white">Otro div</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col divMenu">
        <div class="container ">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <img src="Imagenes/.png" class="img-fluid" style="width: 80px" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div style="float: right; height: 100%">
                <nav style="height: inherit" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  ">

                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                        </button>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav" style="height: inherit; ">
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="margin: 10px;" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">HOME</a>

                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" style="margin: 10px;" href="#">MENU1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" style="margin: 10px;" href="#">MENU2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" style="margin: 10px;" href="#">MENU3</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%------------------------------------------ CUADROS SERVICIO -------------------------------------------------------------------%>
      <div class="row " style="clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);  ">
        <div class="col " style="background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqdRNTyC_vki0Q_xo41JBmJIIFNhd3YKz2ZQgqWwaZLz23R3Df&s); background-size:  100%  100%; background-repeat: no-repeat ;">
          <div class="container ">
            <div class="row rowHome" id="services">
              <div class="col ">
                <div class="container" style="width: 80%; margin-top: 30px; text-align: center">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/analis.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/servicio.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/personalizada.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/celular.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/mano.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="divServicio">
                        <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/engranes.png" style="margin-top: -40px; position: relative;" />
                        <label class="textServicios "><strong>TEXTO1</strong></label><br />
                        <label class="descServicios ">Descripcion del texto</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row mb-5 ">
                    <div class="col-md-12 d-inline-block  ">
                      <asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-primary btnSaberMas " ID="btnSaberMas" Text="Saber Más" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row mb-5 ">
                    <div class="col-md-12 d-inline-block  ">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row " style="clip-path: polygon(0px 20%, 100% 29px, 100% 100%, 0px 90%);background-image: url(Imagenes/fondo_puntos.png),url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-Eu6AKnvOfQ0msPIhWDJRRyKrOEsyKw27v7umxFrp23HKg3DG&s); background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat ; position: static; margin-top: -100px; width: 100%">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="container" style="margin-top: 90px; text-align: center">
            <div class="slide-left">
              <div class="inner">
                <div class="row ">

                  <div class="col col-sm-3 " style="margin-top: 40px">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWPfWn1I4P_E70snKLVtXTBb-NI7OnDXFEu5Rv1p8zIOosZPfm&s    " class="img-fluid" />
                  </div>


                </div>
                <div class="row ">

                  <div class="col col-sm-3 " style="margin-top: 40px">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWPfWn1I4P_E70snKLVtXTBb-NI7OnDXFEu5Rv1p8zIOosZPfm&s    " class="img-fluid" />
                  </div>


                </div>

              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div class="container  " style="margin-top: 90px;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4  " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs1" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div id="divContenido" class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " id="ima1" src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4   " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs4" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4   " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs5" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>




            </div>
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-sm-4  " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4   " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs2" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4   " style="padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 0;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="text-align: center" id="divs3" class="square h-100 row align-items-center">
                  <div class="content ">
                    <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_diagnosis.png" />
                    <label class="textServicios2 "><strong>TEXTO</strong></label><br />
                    <label class="descServicios2 ">Descripcion</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>

  <footer style="background-color :black ; padding-top: 1px; margin-top: 150px">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 90px; text-align: center">
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/facebook_CIO.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="col ">
          <label style="color: white">footer....</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="col ">
          <label style="color: white"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="col ">
          <img class="img-fluid " src="Imagenes/icono_facebook.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row rowHome" style="background-color: #000103 !important; opacity: 0.90">

        <div class="col-sm-8 Redes">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-linkedin" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 Redes">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</form>
```

Comment: Intene no ponerlo sin un valor en pixeles, lo deje como comentas, pero tampoco me funciono, estoy usando media query, pero es mucho trabajo casi tengo que acomodar mi diseño por cada pixel